# How to handle empty session cache when "no-store" in php?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I am using:

```
session_cache_limiter('no-store');
```

Because I want when I go to the next page the previous page values remain the same and do not change. And this works fine for me.

But the problem is I have to empty one session before going to the next page.

I am empty the session like below:

```
    $_SESSION['abcde'] = "";
```

But the problem is when I return to the page where I use

```
session_cache_limiter('no-store');
$_SESSION['abcde'] = ""; // Here the session abcde still have the value and do not empty
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you mean when you said "the problem is I have to empty one session"
but i can suggest you use

```
unset($_SESSION['abcde']); // for destroy session
```

or

```
$_SESSION['abcde'] = null; // for replace null instead of the previous value
```

i hope this is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to call `session_cache_limiter()` before `session_start()`
I still think you should use `'nocache'` instead of `'no-store'` see possible values of session_cache_limiter https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-cache-limiter.php

When you go to next page and want to have previous values remain, it is doing in right.
First page (e.g. index.php) you set `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';`
next page you have `$_SESSION['foo'] == 'bar'` remaining of the first page so you want to do something else?
Try make the session-array deeper, make a array-key for each page that was visited
page 1: index.php

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
session_start();
echo 'Session at the start:<pre>' . print_r( $_SESSION, 1 ) . '</pre>';
$_SESSION['index'] = array( 'foo' => 'bar');
echo 'Session now:<pre>' . print_r( $_SESSION, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

page 2: page2.php

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
session_start();
// here $_SESSION contains index => array( 'foo' => 'bar' )
echo 'Session at the start:<pre>' . print_r( $_SESSION, 1 ) . '</pre>';
$_SESSION['page2'] = array( 'some' => 'value');
echo 'Session now:<pre>' . print_r( $_SESSION, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```